# High CPU usage by Service Host: Local System (Win10, 64-bit): ntoskrnl.exe!KeSynchronizeExecution + others

Tags: windows-10, performance, cpu-usage

Here are screen-shots from Process Explorer which identifies ntoskrnl.exe!KeSynchronizeExecution as one of the ever-running processes:

[image: Screen-shot of a Process Explorer System Idle Processes&svhost.exe threads]

I don't know what to do with this info and cursory google search didn't yield much.

Comment: If you open a normal task manager to Details tab, find the svhost.exe that uses a lot of cpu, right click it and select "go to services", this will highlight all services related to that instance of svhost.exe. This will narrow the search for the root cause.

Comment: Resolved the issue by what I think was turning off "Give me tips about Windows" in Devide Manage/System/Notifications.